# Formulas math en PHP con distintas varibales

Tags: php, math

Quiero poder hacer una tabla donde el usuario guarde formulas de matemáticas, para luego llamarlas y poder ejecutarlas dependiendo de las variables que este le haya declado.

Encontré este ejemplo

```
   $formula = ‘X/100 + 0.1’;

   saveFormula($formula);

   $result = getFormula();

   $precio = 22.1;
   foreach($result as $row)
   {
        $calculation = str_replace(‘X’, $precio, $row[‘formula’]);
        echo $calculation; /* Al parecer no me funciona por que estoy guardando 
                              $formula como comillas ' ' */
    }
```

Bueno si llegara a funcionar me gustaría poder calcular con mas variables.

Ejemplo

Guardo esta formula en en mi `db`, el campo es `TEXT`

```
((2.767 * (X*1000-Y) + 831.58)
```

Y después el usuario ingresa `X` y `Y` en una input que esta busque la formula y la calcule.

Nose si esta es la mejor forma de hacer cálculos o mejor mediante Ajax solamente obtener la formula en `javascripts` calcular. De antemanos muchas gracias

Comment: Sólo tienes que obtener la fórmula: `((2.767 * (X*1000-Y) + 831.58)` y en el cliente hacer un replace de `X` y de `Y` por los valores. O calcularlo en el servidor y devolverlo al cliente. Del primer modo el servidor va más suave, del segundo modo cargas más al servidor. Esto tiene consecuencias, sobre todo si son millones de clientes.

Comment: donde encontraste ese ejemplo? seria interesante para ver si lo entendiste correctamente

Comment: @gbianchi https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243272/8766401

Comment: Te falta un paso.. usar eval, que **no se recomienda usar nunca** porque el usuario podria usarlo de forma mal intencionada...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿por qué hay que usar `eval`? Creo que reemplazando `X` por el valor daría el resultado, ¿no?

Comment: no.. php no ejecuta el contenido de una variable, solo le va a devolver el string como esta. Pide que la calcule, echo solo le devolvera la variable sea cual sea.. @A.Cedano

Comment: @gbianchi  Pero yo digo en el cliente. Se recupera la fórmula en el servidor, y se calcula en el cliente, reemplazando `X` e `Y` por los valores. Si no entendí mal, la fórmulas están en el servidor. O, se puede pasar los valores al servidor y calcular allí, devolviendo el resultado al cliente, o traer la fórmula al cliente y calcular allí reemplazando. Por eso no entiendo lo de usar `eval` en este caso.

Comment: si no usas eval, como vas a calcular el valor de esa formula? solo estarias devolviendo la formula @A.Cedano.. Igual, eval es un peligro latente y no se deberia usar nunca

Comment: @gbianchi se puede pedir la fórmula al servidor, como pides el valor "Pepe". El OP dice que la fórmula es una cadena que está guardada en la base de datos. Pides la cadena y luego la usas como fórmula en el cliente.

Comment: @A.Cedano o entendemos cosas diferentes de la pregunta, o te salteaste esta parte: "Y después el usuario ingresa X y Y en una input que esta busque la formula y la calcule." si no usa eval, como la calcula?

Comment: @gbianchi ahí una propuesta para hacerlo desde el cliente, evitando los riesgos de usar `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que planteas se puede resolver de dos maneras: del lado del cliente o del lado del servidor.

Resolverlo del lado del cliente sería lo mejor, sobre todo si el código está destinado a millones de usuarios, porque ahorraría trabajo al servidor.

Una forma de hacerlo evitando `eval`, sería mediante el uso de `new Function`, [tal y como se recomienda en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval), para evitar los posibles riesgos del uso de `eval`.

Aquí suponemos que se recupera del servidor la fórmula siguiente:

```
((2.767 * (X*1000-Y) + 831.58))
```

OJO, le falta un paréntesis a tu fórmula...

La almacenamos en una variable cualquiera. Recuperamos igualmente los valores de `X` y de `Y` de sus respectivos inputs y hacemos un `replace` de los caracteres `X` e `Y` en la fórmula por los valores que tengan en el input.

Luego, mediante `new Function` podremos obtener el valor sin riesgo.

```js
var inputX=7;
var inputY=44;
var phpFormula='((2.767 * (X*1000-Y) + 831.58))';
var newFormula=phpFormula.replace('X',inputX).replace('Y',inputY);

console.log(newFormula);

let finalValue = (new Function('return '+newFormula)())
console.log('Resultado:', finalValue)
```

Como decía al principio, también puedes enviar los valores de los inputs al servidor vía Ajax, hacer el cálculo allí y devolverlo al cliente.